# Virtual Terminal/Pseudo-console buffer size events for Windows Terminal

Tags: c#, .net, windows-terminal

What is the preferred way to respond to changes in the buffer size for Windows Terminal?
With an old-school command prompt, I would get a reference to the window handle for the console and hook the events from there.
Is there an equivalent for PseudoConsoles?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you'd use `ReadConsoleInput` as in [Reading Input Buffer Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) to listen for `WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_EVENT` messages.

Alas, I'm not familiar enough with C# to know the idiomatic way of doing this. Surprisingly, I'm not seeing a simplified version of that in the [Console](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console?view=net-6.0) API. You might need to pinvoke to do this.